# How to perform unit testing on a void method in web api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have a update method in webAPI and that is a void method and I want to perform unit testing on that method.How do I do that??

Not Found any solution.

Below is webapi controller method :-

```
[HttpPut]      
public void UpdatePushNotification(PushNotificationQueueBO pushnotificationqueueBO)
{
   PushNotificationQueueBO.UpdatePushNotificationQueue(pushnotificationqueueBO);
}
```

Below is the unit test case for above method

```
[TestMethod]
public void UpdatePushNotificationQueue_ShouldUpdate()
{        
    var item = GetDemoPushNotificationQueue();      

    var controller = new PushNotificationQueueController();

    var result = controller.UpdatePushNotification(item) as ;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);       
}
```

I want what do I write after as in

```
var result = controller.UpdatePushNotification(item) as ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller method is `void` so there is no return type and nothing to cast it to.

I believe this to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

`void` controller actions will always return  HTTP Status Code 200 OK at run-time except when an exception is thrown.

Based on the tags in original post the assumption is that the mentioned controller is an `ApiController`

which means that the controller can be refactored to

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult UpdatePushNotification(PushNotificationQueueBO pushnotificationqueueBO) {
    PushNotificationQueueBO.UpdatePushNotificationQueue(pushnotificationqueueBO);
    return Ok();
}
```

There is also the option to wrap it in a try-catch in case of errors

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult UpdatePushNotification(PushNotificationQueueBO pushnotificationqueueBO) {
    try {
        PushNotificationQueueBO.UpdatePushNotificationQueue(pushnotificationqueueBO);
        return Ok();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
        //OR
        //return InternalServerError()
    }
}
```

But that is more of a cross-cutting concern that can be handled by action filters.

This would then allow for an actual return type to be asserted

```
//...omitted for brevity

IHttpActionResult result = controller.UpdatePushNotification(item);

Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```

The `PushNotificationQueueBO` business object however, appears to be making a static member call.

```
PushNotificationQueueBO.UpdatePushNotificationQueue(pushnotificationqueueBO);
```

This makes it difficult to unit test the encapsulated API method call in isolation and may result in undesired behavior.

It is suggested that the static business object call be encapsulated behind an abstraction and implementation that can be replaced by a mock when testing in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can test a void function in different ways and it depends on what the void method does. For example, if a void method increments the numeric value of a property of its class, then you can use that property in your test. In your case, your void method performs this action;

```
PushNotificationQueueBO.UpdatePushNotificationQueue(pushnotificationqueueBO);
```

Firstly, identify what this action does and what it affects. For example, if this method's action performs a manipulation on a queue object, then you can test this object as a result of the void method.